# spring data redis reactive read LocaldateTime cast error

Tags: jackson, spring-data, spring-data-redis, spring-data-redis-reactive

I use spring Data Redis Reactive framework and spring Boot version is 2.3.0.

Here is my Redis configuration:

```
  @Bean("reactiveRedisTemplate")
public ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, Object> reactiveRedisTemplateString(ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jacksonSerializer = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(Object.class);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.ALL, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    objectMapper.enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL);
    objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
    JavaTimeModule timeModule = new JavaTimeModule();
    timeModule.addSerializer(Date.class, new DateSerializer(Boolean.FALSE, new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
    timeModule.addSerializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
    timeModule.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
    timeModule.addSerializer(LocalTime.class, new LocalTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss")));
    timeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
    timeModule.addDeserializer(LocalDate.class, new LocalDateDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
    timeModule.addDeserializer(LocalTime.class, new LocalTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss")));
    objectMapper.setDefaultPropertyInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(LaissezFaireSubTypeValidator.instance,
            ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL, JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY);
    objectMapper.registerModule(timeModule).registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule()).registerModules(ObjectMapper.findModules());
    jacksonSerializer.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);

    final StringRedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();
    RedisSerializationContext<String , Object> serializationContext = RedisSerializationContext
            .<String, Object>newSerializationContext()
            .key(stringRedisSerializer)
            .value(jacksonSerializer)
            .hashKey(stringRedisSerializer)
            .hashValue(jacksonSerializer)
            .build();

    return new ReactiveRedisTemplate(connectionFactory, serializationContext);
}
```

I set up a LocalDateTime object with the hashoperations.put method to display the following form in Redis:

```
key hashKey "2020-06-23 16:42:44"
```

When I use Mono<LocalDateTime>Mono = hashoperations.get(key,hashKey) to get the value, the following exception occurs:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class java.time.LocalDateTime (java.lang.String and java.time.LocalDateTime are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilter.java:93)
at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76)
```

But when LocalDateTime is a property of an object, there is no problem.

I don't know how to solve it. Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it

change DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL to DefaultTyping.EVERYTHING

This will take the type of java.time.LocalDateTime